# How do I get an external dataset-sourced image to remain anchored in an SSRS report?

Tags: image, reporting-services, dataset, external

The image of my SSRS report displays on the far right side of the header.  It does not remain anchored to the location in which it was inserted.

Tried bringing it forward and the header text backward, but it fails to remail in place. I am placing in on top of other header text.

Comment: It sounds like you are trying to overlap objects in the report? If you are then try to avoid this practice, the results will vary depending on which renderer is used and it rarely works as you think it should. If you need more help I suggest you show your current report design and expected output, then people may be able to offer alternative approaches.